# Wordpress 3.4 deregister jQuery

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After upgrading WP from 3.3 to 3.4 wp_deregister_script('jquery'); seems to not work anymore (jQuery provided by WP is visible in  section).

Deregister script is included in functions.php file of my theme and looks like this:

```
    if( !is_admin()){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
}
```

After the upgrade I was trying to custom this, but nothing actually works. For example, i also tried to dequeue the script, but still no go.

```
if( !is_admin()){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');

}
```

Looking forward your opinions and any idea of possible solution.

Comment: You should not deregister wp own jQuery . There is almost no use case where this can be applied . it is just [wrong](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) and in all likelihood will break your theme compatibility with other plugins , and sometimes with wp core itself .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hook` to do that

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_func' );
function my_enque_func()
{
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script(...); // Register your own script
}
```

About [**wp_register_script**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script).

Comment: `if( !is_admin()){
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_func' );
    function my_enque_func()
    {
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    }

}`

Doesn't work, isn't 'admin_enqueue_scripts' works only for scripts included in wp-admin area?

Comment: If so you can try `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enque_func');` instead.

Comment: Actually using `admin_enqueue_scripts` to de-register script in admin side you don't need to chack `if(is_admin())`.

Comment: Thank you @Sheikh. Sadly, deregister_script('jquery') removed also next-gen gallery scripts. Did Wordpress changed something with those functions on 3.4?

Comment: No, AFAIK but how do you know that `next-gen gallery scripts` has been removed ?

Comment: If you only de-register `jquery` and doesn't register another copy of `jquery` then any plugin depended on `jQuery` won't work, so make sure you register your own `jQuery` after de-registering the original `jquery`

Comment: Thank you again. Changed all inclusion of script from hardcoded in header.php to functions.php. Did the work and now works like a charm. Regards.

Comment: although the technical validity of the answer is correct, the whole process by itself is [very wrong](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/). one should not encourage people to do so :-)

Comment: Agreed @ObmerkKronen and thanks for the link, I'll look into it if I find more than I know :-).